# Can't set cookie from backend to frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session, cookies

I have a backend and a frontend hosted on different containers, I want to set a cookie from my backend to frontend but I can't seem to set a cookie. Could you please help me with that. I am using express-session and these are the configurations for cors and express-session.

```
const corsOptions = {
  origin: [
    "https://myfrontend.a.run.app",
    "https://myfrontend.a.run.app/signup",
    "https://myfrontend.a.run.app/signin",
  ],
  methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
  credentials: true, // If you are using cookies or sessions
  exposedHeaders: ["set-cookie"],
};

const sessionOptions = {
  name: "sessionCookie",
  secret: "mysecret",
  saveUninitialized: false,
  resave: false,
  cookie: {
    secure: true,
    httpOnly: true,
    domain: "myfrontend.a.run.app",
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 30,
    sameSite: "None",
  },
};
```

And this is the request in the frontend

```
import axios from "axios";

const config = {
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    "Origin-Allow-Credentials": true,
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
  },
};

const endpoint = "https://mybackend.a.run.app/signup";

export default async function SignUp(
  username: string,
  password: string,
  email: string
) {
  return axios.post(endpoint,{username,password,email},config);
}
```

Comment: add the `package.json` file to your question.

Comment: Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).